# Use bcp in azure function powershell

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, bcp

I have a problem I create an azure fuction app in powershell. insinde my script, i use bcp command it's work perfecly in local but when I deploy it I have in output "The term 'bcp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" i would like insert the right module in requirement.psd1 ut I search a long time with no result. Do you know what's module I have to install?

Comment: `bcp` isn't a module, it's an application, and needs to be installed. [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The old Azure document talked about [BCP in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/bcp-in-azure-functions). May it can help you. I don't know if it still works now.  This link may be more clear: https://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2016/12/04/bcp-in-azure-functions/.

Comment: Another question, you'd better share us the powershell  scipt for us.